# MS Bat file user input sent to text file causing ipconfig to fail

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to creat a bat file that asks for an input, puts the input in a text file. And then dumps the results of ipconfig at the end of the text file. Here is what i got so far.

```
@echo off
SET /P User=Type username.
@echo %User% >> C:\ipconfig.txt
ipconfig >> C:\ipconfig.txt
pause
```

when i run this the cmd window hangs and the text file contains this.

```
ant
Type username.
```

what am i doing wrong here. Please help.

Thanks in avance.
ant

Comment: You called the batch file ipconfig, didn't you?  Try a different name.

Comment: haha.   so simple.   thanks a lot.   so if i understand that correctly.  it was calling itself rather than the function.

Comment: Yep.  Exactly. Function=executable in your case.  We all do it at some stage. :)

Answer (score 1):

[antnt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5169677/antnt) made 2 mistakes:

1. Batch file was named `ipconfig.bat`.
2. Inside batch file `ipconfig` was called without file extension and full path.

The command processor `cmd.exe` does following on running an application from within a batch file or on command prompt specified without file extension and full path on example `ipconfig`.

1. It compares the string `ipconfig` against the list of internal commands like `dir`, `echo`, `rem`, etc.
   Enter in a command prompt window `help` to see a list of standard commands whereby not all of them are internal commands of `cmd.exe`.
2. It searches next in current directory for `ipconfig.*`.

   - If there is a positive match, it checks if any file extension listed in environment variable **PATHEXT** appended after `ipconfig.` is found in current directory.
   - If a file extension in **PATHEXT** appended after also appended `.` matches the name of a file in current directory, this file is executed.
3. In case of no file in current directory matches `ipconfig.*` with an extension listed in **PATHEXT**, the command processor recursively applies above described search on every directory specified in environment variable **PATH**.

The order of the file extensions in **PATHEXT** determines which executable is executed first if there is for example in current directory `ipconfig.bat` and `ipconfig.exe`.

The order of directory paths in **PATH** determines the search order of the other directories.

The values of **PATH** and **PATHEXT** can be seen by opening a command prompt window and running `set path` which lists all environment variables starting with string `path`.

It is possible to modify **PATH** and **PATHEXT** on command prompt or in a batch file locally before calling other batch files or applications to change the directory and/or file extension lists for those child processes as for examples IDE often do before calling a compiler during build process.

So in this case the batch file `ipconfig.bat` executed itself in current directory instead of `ipconfig.exe` in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. The batch file is renamed to something different than `ipconfig.bat`.
2. The console application `ipconfig.exe` is specified with file extension and full path in the batch file.

For the second solution the batch file could look like:

```
@echo off
set /P "User=Type user name: "
echo %User%>"%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
set "User="
%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe>>"%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
type "%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
echo.
del "%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
pause
```

Or perhaps even better without user prompt:

```
@echo off
echo User %USERNAME% on computer %COMPUTERNAME%>"%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe>>"%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
type "%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
echo.
del "%TEMP%\ipconfig.txt"
pause
```

My advice: In batch files specify applications to execute always with full path and with file extension even for standard applications of Windows if that is possible because application directory as well as the file extension is well known. This avoids possible problems in future just because of list of directories in **PATH** and/or file extensions in **PATHEXT** changed.